# Isabelle labeled graph definition

Tags: functional-programming, isabelle, hol

I am trying to define some vertex labels in Isabelle HOL and have a problem with the successor definition:

```
  record ('v,'w) graph =
    nodes :: "('v×'w) set"
    edges :: "(('v×'w) × ('v×'w)) set"

 definition succ :: "('v,'w) graph ⇒'v ⇒ ('v,'w) set"
    where "succ G v ≡ {(v',w). ((v,w),(v',w))∈edges G}"
```

It says "Bad number of arguments for type constructor: "Set.set"", does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`succ` shall probably return a set of vertex-label pairs `'v × 'w`, so want to write

```
definition succ :: "('v,'w) graph ⇒'v ⇒ ('v × 'w) set"
```

Comment: Can you open up a separate question that contains all relevant declarations? E.g., I don't know what the locale `valid_graph` specifies.